# Updating href using URLSearchParams instead of appending

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that updates the result href. At the moment it keeps on appending my result at the end of my href every time the states are updated. How do I change my function below and use `URLSearchParams` instead to update everything after `?`?

```
  resultHref(result) {
    let href = result.href;

    const { start_date, end_date } = this.props.params;
    const queryString = serialize({ start_date, end_date });

    if (queryString !== '?') {
      href += queryString;
    }

    return href;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe replace `href += queryString` with `href = queryString`?

Comment: That wouldn't work as that replaced everything. I still need to take into account start_date and end_date in my href